# Почему скрипт на python3 не пишет данные в файл, когда запущен из crontab?

Tags: python, python-3.x, crontab

Вот простейшая запись в файл на **python3**:

```
mes = 'hehe\n';
with open('events.log', 'a+') as f:
    f.write(mes)
```

При запуске с консоли **linux** работает как положено.
Однако, когда я запускаю скрипт при помощи **crontab** ничего не работает, записи в файле нет вообще. Запуск идет с правами root.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3.5 /home/username/test.py > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Если вызывать так, тоже неработает:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3.5 /home/username/test.py
```

Выводы `stderr` ничего не возвращают (/home/username/errors.log пуст)

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3.5 /home/username/test.py > /dev/null 2>> /home/username/errors.log
```

Как быть, кто знает в чём может быть дело?

Answer (score 1):

Пробовали так?

```
* * * * * myjob.sh >> /var/log/myjob.log 2>&1
```

[что такое 2>&1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/818284/12785139)

События `cron`:

- /var/log/cron
- /var/log/syslog
- journalctl | grep cron
- journalctl -u cron

Comment: Спасибо но это все не то, дело в путях к файлу, в python3 необходимо указывать абсолютные пути

Answer (score 0):

В python3 все пути к файлам необходимо указывать как абсолютные а не как относительные

```
install_dir = '/usr/local/my_program'
mes = 'hehe\n';
with open(instal_dir+'/events.log', 'a+') as f:
    f.write(mes)
```

Тогда не важно кто запускает вашу программу, вы с консоли linux или сторонний скрипт например crontab , все будет работать

Comment: Такой необходимости нет, относительные пути означают запись файла **относительно текущего каталога**. А если вы в cron не проконтролировали, какой каталог является текущим, то значит вы где-то создали новый файл events.log и сами не знаете где

Comment: Верно, создал новый файл events.log, и знаю где. Когда скрипты запускает crontab то прописанные в них относительные пути будут считатся не от текущего каталога скрипта а от каталога где находится crontab. Точно так же со всеми программами которые теоретически могли бы запустить этот python скрипт. Лучше взять себе в хорошую привычку прописывать в своих скриптах абсолютные пути